# Appengine: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address on socket.connect

Tags: java, sockets, google-app-engine

I am using `java.net.Socket.connect()` to connect to an FTP server in passive mode on AppEngine.  It works around 30% of the time, but I usually get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: System error: errno: 99, detail:Cannot assign requested address
```

It sounds as though the host simply doesn't have any available ports for outgoing connections (I am not requesting a specific port.)  I get the same result when I use `new java.net.Socket()`  I would appreciate any thoughts as to what might be happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of same error while opening sockets for FTP, but error rate is decreased after setting `socket.setSoLinger(true, 0)` and `socket.setReuseAddress(true)`.

Comment: That may have made it somewhat better, but I am still getting the error in question more often than not.